# jQuery works in jsFiddle but not on my computer

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I'm new to jQuery and have been scratching my head all day trying to determine why this script runs in jsFiddle but not on my computer. I do not have a server setup, I am merely launching the html in my browser from the desktop.

The code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Dubr/164/. However when I create the following html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>this better work</title>

<script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#myfrom').fadeOut("slow", function(){
    var dot = $("<div id='foo'>Goodmorning Mr. Patti<br/><br/>Thank you.</div>".hide();
    $(this).replaceWith(dot);
    $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    });
    </script> 
<style type="text/css">

#container{
width:342px;
height:170px;
padding:10px;
background-color:grey;
}
#myform{
width:322px;
height:100px;
color:#6F6F6F;
padding: 0px;
outline:none;
background-color:white;
}
#foo{
width:322px;
height:100px;
color:#6F6F6F;
padding: 0px;
outline:none;
background-color:white;
}
#submit{
color:#6F6F6F;
padding: 10px 2px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
outline:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="myform">
<p> blah blah blah blah blah </p>
 <input id="submit" value="send" type="submit"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get no results when I click the submit button. Please help, I've spent 6 hours on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you include jQuery? jQuery is auto-loaded in Jfiddler but you have to otherwise load it manually.

Comment: yes...see line 5 <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: @JohnSmith Does the `jquery-latest.js` file exist in the same directory as your HTML file? Do you see anything in your browser's error console?

Comment: Do it on dom ready like I posted above. Why are you using jQ 1.5? Latest is 1.7.1...

Comment: @clclanrs I did, stll no results.

Answer (score 6):

You have to execute the code on DOM ready. Wrap your code in `$(function(){ });` Also, you're missing a `)`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $('#myfrom').fadeOut("slow", function () {
            var dot = $("<div id='foo'>Goodmorning Mr. Patti<br/><br/>Thank you.</div>").hide();
            $(this).replaceWith(dot);
            $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });

});
```

**EDIT:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This better work</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $('#myfrom').fadeOut("slow", function () {
            var dot = $("<div id='foo'>Goodmorning Mr. Patti<br/><br/>Thank you.</div>").hide();
            $(this).replaceWith(dot);
            $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="myform">
            <p> blah blah blah blah blah </p>
            <input id="submit" value="send" type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and reason it works in fiddle is the setting on left for onload

Comment: **@John Smith** are you properly including the jQuery library?

Comment: I thought I was properly including it with line 5 <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>. How do I duplicate the onload functionality of jsfiddle?

Comment: This example shows you the onload functionality, also seen as `$(document).ready(function() {...` or in this answer the short-hand version, `$(function () {...`

Comment: changing my code to this: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $('#myfrom').fadeOut("slow", function () {
            var dot = $("<div id='foo'>Goodmorning Mr. Patti<br/><br/>Thank you.</div>").hide();
            $(this).replaceWith(dot);
            $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
});
 </script>

Comment: @elclanrs please specify where I am mission a )

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end of `...Thank you.</div>")` <-- There! But in your fiddle it's fine. See edit.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, it works because you are binding your submit `click` event but that button is not in a `<form>` tag. If locally you are using a form tag, you will get different functionality as the form submit may get priority over the button click event.

Comment: @shanabus thats it! Once I moved the submit button outside of the <form></form> tag the Jquery function fired and performed properly. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith, awesome, I'm glad that worked.  I've updated my answer to include this solution in case you feeling like marking my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with the code you posted that might help.

- Start your document by declaring the doctype - `<!DOCTYPE html>`

or if using HTML 4 specs, at least specify the script type:

- Declare the javascript type in your jquery reference - `type="text/javascript"`

**UPDATE** - based on recent comments

In your jsfiddle, it works because you are binding your submit click event but that button is not in a `<form>` tag. If locally you are using a form tag, you will get different functionality as the form submit may get priority over the button click event.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Whilst good practice, I doubt either of these are creating a problem.

Comment: If you declare HTML5 doctype then you don't need `type="text/javascript"`, it's already implied...

Comment: While I agree that neither may directly solve the problem, you are wrong about #2 according to the spec: This attribute specifies the scripting language of the element's contents and overrides the default scripting language. The scripting language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript"). Authors must supply a value for this attribute. There is no default value for this attribute. -- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html

Comment: **@shanabus** that's true for html4, but your step 1 declares html5 doctype, where `text-javascript` is indeed the default value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer even the OP has already said these didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In all such doubts it is always to check the source of http://jsfiddle.net/draft/ this is the last fiddle rendered with hitting [Run]. Check the source and compare it with your file.