# JavaScript won't run, says element is null, but code runs in fiddle

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm building a thymeleaf and spring project with the java configuration. When I try out this code in a [jsfiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oyw5yaLh/) it works fine, but when I try to run it in my application I get this:
`TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`.

There is nothing wrong in the imports of the javascrips and the source renders them and the html just fine.

The code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="buybutton" th:id="buybutton" th:text="#{cart.buy}">Buy</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('buybutton').addEventListener("click", function(e){
   console.log("bought"); 
});
```

Thymeleaf configuration (if it is of any importance):

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setOrder(1);
            resolver.setCacheable(false);
            resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return resolver;
}

}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('buybutton2')` change to  `document.getElementById('buybutton')` use correct ID name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery works in jsFiddle but not on my computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577047/jquery-works-in-jsfiddle-but-not-on-my-computer)

Comment: The IDs are matching in my code ,the button2 is a leftover from me trying to add another element. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add click event only when the DOM is ready.

**NOTE:** In the case of jsfiddle this is **default behaviour**.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  document.getElementById('buybutton').addEventListener("click", function(e){
   console.log("bought"); 
  });
});
```